# How to pass dynamic inputs for a command on windows remote machine using python pypsexec.client library

Tags: python-3.x

I am executing commands on windows remote machine using python pypsexec.client library from a local windows machine where python script is written.
Below is the command that I am trying to execute from the python script:
[image]

How do I pass name and details parameters form the script?
Below is the my script:

```
from pypsexec.client import Client
ip = '10.X.X.X'
try:
    conn = Client(ip, 'administrator', 'password', encrypt='False')
    conn.connect()
    conn.create_service()
    print('service created for following "{}".......\n\n'.format(ip))
    callback = r"""C:\Progra~1\Nimsoft\bin\pu -u administrator -p password 
                   /CHOSERVER1_domain/CHOSERVER1_hub/CHOSERVER1/hub getrobots"""
    stdout, stderr, rc = conn.run_executable('cmd.exe',arguments='''/c 
                                             {}'''.format(callback),stdin=None)
    stdout = str(stdout, 'utf-8');stderr = str(stderr, 'utf-8')
    print(stdout)
except Exception as e:
    print('Below exception occured .....\n')
    print(e)
    print()
```

While running the above script terminal is waiting for the name,details parameters which has mentioned on screenshot.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s possible at all but it’s bad practice. Can you instead use certificates?

Comment: Thanks @anonjnr on update, Could you please tell me which certificates I can use.

Comment: I’m sorry I misunderstood the question. But see my answer, probably it can help you!