# How send command or data after running an executable through pypsexec?

Tags: python, psexec

I used the following Python script to run an executable remotely and I can send input data through `stdin`.

```py
from pypsexec.client import Client

c = Client("my_ip", username="myusername", password="mypassword")

c.connect()
try:
    c.create_service()

    stdin b'first-input\nsecond-input\n'
    stdout, stderr, rc = c.run_executable("app.exe", stdin=stdin)
    print(stdout)
finally:
    c.remove_service()
    c.disconnect()
```

I need to send my data after executing my application.

Comment: When you specify `interactive=true`, the output is displayed on the console of the remote machine and input is expected to come from there.  If you want to feed input and read output, don't specify `interactive`, and pass a byte string or generator function as the `stdin` parameter.

Comment: My remote program displays some text in the beginning but I am not able to print this with stdout. And I tried to enter input with stdin like this `stdout, stderr, rc, stdin = c.run_executable("my.exe")` and `stdin.write(b'one\none\none\n')` but I got no output.

Comment: Look at the documentation, please.  `stdin` is a parameter to `run_executable`, it's not one of the return values.  This is not as flexible as `subprocess.Popen`.  You can't interact with the app, you have to provide a canned input.

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are also parameters so it is the reason I thought I can use `stdin` in the return values. Could you provide an example of the usage of stdin with `pypsexec`?

Comment: I had never heard of this package before your question.  I learned what I did by (gasp) reading the documentation.  They have examples.  https://github.com/jborean93/pypsexec

Comment: I find the way how to use `stdin` but it is not exactly that I want. I need to send my data after to run my program. I find a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607291/how-to-pass-dynamic-inputs-for-a-command-on-windows-remote-machine-using-python/59622849#59622849

Comment: If your task can't be handled with a canned input stream, then `pypsexec` is not the tool for you.  You may need to install an SSH server, or perhaps write your own TCP server to pass commands across.

Comment: I think SSH server is the best option for me. thanks for your help. I don't know why I don't think about the SSH server before!